# SQL Splitting Rows Into Multiple Rows Based on Condition

Tags: sql

I have the below table:

| Account | Credit | Debt | Net | ItemCount | InvoiceNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 1300 | 150 | 1150 | 2 | 10 |
| AAA | 500 | 50 | 450 | 12 | 20 |
| AAA | 1800 | 650 | 1150 | 29 | 30 |

No record can have a higher count than 10 items so anything over 10 must be split into multiples of 10 until the last remaining value (which could be less than 10)

I am trying to automate this in SQL and have not been able to come up with an idea that works, I would like something to look at the above table and spit out the following:

| Account | Credit | Debt | Net | ItemCount | InvoiceNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 1300 | 150 | 1150 | 2 | 10 |
| AAA | 500 | 50 | 450 | 10 | 20 |
| AAA | 500 | 50 | 450 | 2 | 30 |
| AAA | 1800 | 650 | 1150 | 10 | 10 |
| AAA | 1800 | 650 | 1150 | 10 | 20 |
| AAA | 1800 | 650 | 1150 | 9 | 30 |

Any thoughts on how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Please only tag a **SINGLE** RDBMS i.e. the one you want your solution it! Spam tagging only annoys people.

Comment: You can tag one... the one you are using... just not lots

Comment: You almost certainly need to write code to achieve this. I doubt it is possible using a pure SQL solution

Answer (score 0):

If you work with SQL Server, this should do the trick for you

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
    [Account] varchar(3), 
    [Credit] int, 
    [Debt] int, 
    [Net] int, 
    [ItemCount] int,
    [InvoiceNumber] int
);
    
INSERT INTO #Table1 ([Account], [Credit], [Debt], [Net], [ItemCount], [InvoiceNumber])
VALUES
    ('AAA', 1300, 150, 1150, 2, 10),
    ('AAA', 500, 50, 450, 12, 20),
    ('AAA', 1800, 650, 1150, 29, 30)
;

WITH cte_numbers([Account] , [Credit] , [Debt] , [Net] , [ItemCount] , [InvoiceNumber] , itemcountzero, currentitmecount) 
AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        (itemcount % 10) AS itemcountzero, 
        (itemcount) AS currentitmecount
    FROM
        #Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT    
        t.[Account] , t.[Credit] , t.[Debt] , t.[Net] , t.[ItemCount] , t.[InvoiceNumber] , c.itemcountzero, (c.currentitmecount-10)
    FROM  
        #Table1 t
    INNER JOIN
        cte_numbers c ON t.[InvoiceNumber] = c.[InvoiceNumber] 
                      AND (c.currentitmecount-10) >= c.itemcountzero 
                      -- AND (currentitmecount-10) > 0
)
SELECT 
    [Account] , [Credit] , [Debt] , [Net] , IIF(currentitmecount > 10, 10 , currentitmecount) as [ItemCount] , [InvoiceNumber]
FROM 
    cte_numbers
ORDER BY
    [InvoiceNumber], currentitmecount DESC;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, recursive CTEs are not supported. I appreciate the prompt response.

Comment: what DB do you use?

Comment: It is Microsoft Azure

Comment: Microsoft Azure mssql? If so it is supported in this DB.

Comment: Azure Synapse / Azure Data Studio. I get the message "Recursive common table expressions are not supported in this version."

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a cursor to iterate through the records and generate as many inserts as you need based on the value that you have